My app works perfectly on Android emulator but shows a white screen at startup when packaged as APK (Expo React Native)
I'm using Expo React Native to build my app. The app works perfectly on both the Android emulator and the web, but when I build it as an APK (using EAS) and install the app on a real Android device, it gets stuck at startup, showing a white screen. Here’s my configuration:
im using:

expo: "~51.0.38",
react: "18.2.0",
react-native: "0.74.5",

Source code on GitHub: open-mushaf-native
//app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Mushaf",
    "slug": "open-mushaf-native",
    "version": "1.0.14",
    "orientation": "default",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.adelpro.openmushafnative"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.adelpro.openmushafnative",
      "playStoreUrl": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adelpro.openmushafnative",
      "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true,
      "jsEngine": "hermes",
      "permissions": [],
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
      "buildProperties": {
        "android": {
          "enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds": true,
          "enableR8": true
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-font",
      "expo-av",
      "expo-secure-store",
      "expo-updates"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true,
      "tsconfigPaths": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "2360a464-857f-4685-8c0f-be166a166847"
      }
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/2360a464-857f-4685-8c0f-be166a166847",
      "enabled": true,
      "checkAutomatically": "ON_LOAD",
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "nativeVersion"
    },
    "owner": "adelpro"
  }
}

//eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "distribution": "internal",
        "resourceClass": "medium",
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle",
        "resourceClass": "medium",
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "channel": "production",
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "track": "internal"
      }
    }
  }
}

